# Pagefold animation with UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to implement page fold animation in one of my app. Using [MPFoldTransition](https://github.com/mpospese/MPFoldTransition) for page fold animation. It provides method for animating UIView and UIViewController transitions.

I want to animate the `UICollectionView` like the page fold. Please guide me, how can I achieve page fold transition on `UICollectionView`.

Is there any way I can convert the current visible cells to `UIView`.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Refer this Github repository for how to animate CollectionView cell and make PageFold animation accordingly.

https://github.com/applidium/ADLivelyCollectionView

Comment: I don't want to animate individual cell. I want to animate complete view page